# False (in a very strange way) result of db_query()

Tags: 7, database

### The context

I'm developing a custom module which includes a simple logging functionality.
Here is the very reduced set of records I first created for test.

**Table: bizaudit_logging** (custom)

[image: Table: bizaudit_logging]

**Table: taxonomy_term_data** (Drupal core)

[image: Table: taxonomy_term_data]

### The query

Here is a query to get the list of the logging contents, with only one notable feature: the `event` resulting field is got from the `event_id` real field through a join to some taxonomy terms.
Nothing more simple than that, isn'it?

```
SELECT LOG.`created`, LOG.`actor_id`, LOG.`client_id`, LOG.`service_id`,
    LOG.`value`, LOG.`other`, TTD.`name` AS "event"
FROM `bizaudit_logging` AS LOG
LEFT OUTER JOIN `taxonomy_term_data` AS TTD ON TTD.`tid` = LOG.`event_id`
ORDER BY `created`
```

Executing it with phpMyAdmin I get the expected result:

[image: query_PMA]

In the context of my module, I'm using `db_query()`, so to be compliant with the Drupal rules the submitted query is slightly different:

```
SELECT LOG.`created`, LOG.`actor_id`, LOG.`client_id`, LOG.`service_id`,
    LOG.`value`, LOG.`other`, TTD.`name` AS "event"
FROM {bizaudit_logging} AS LOG
LEFT OUTER JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} AS TTD ON TTD.`vid` = LOG.`event_id`
ORDER BY `created`
```

As you can check (and unless I'm keeping blind against something obvious), the only difference is that the table names are wrapped in {}.

But here is the result I get (it's transmitted through Ajax hence the format below):

[image: query_Drupal]

There is a double kink:

- The third record appears twice (#2 and #3)
- The `event` field of records #1 to #3 show a false value, which is the one of each previous record (#0 to #2)

Interestingly I noticed that dropping the `JOIN` clause (and indeed the `TTD.name` in the fields list) gives the expected correct result.
So the problem seems to be related to this clause.

But I can't at all imagine how this may happen!

---

EDIT (in response to a comment).

Here is the final part of the Drupal code I'm using:

```
  try {
    foreach (db_query($query, $args, ['fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]) as $row) {
      if (isset($row[$key_field])) {
        $key = $row[$key_field];
        unset($row[$key_field]);
        $result[$key] = $row;
      } else {
        $result[] = $row;
      }
    }
  } catch(PDOException $exception) {
    $result['_error'] = $exception->getMessage();
  }
  return $result;
```

It comes after a lot of stuff to make the final `$query` and `$args` content.
In the current case:

- `$query` is what I exposed above.
- `$args` is an empty array

Also note that the 1st branch of `if (isset($row[$key_field]))` is not involved now: only `$result[] = $row;` is executed, hence the result format showed above.

Comment: Can you show the actual Drupal code you are using please.

Comment: @Jaypan Drupal code: please look at my edited question.